# Confusion about Object.create() and property inheritance

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, why does `boat.calls` increment when I call `sailboat.getHasEngine()`? Also, why is `sailboat.calls` set to 2 after only calling getHasEngine() once?

```js
let vehicle = {
  calls: 0,
  hasEngine: null,
  getHasEngine: function() {
    vehicle.calls = vehicle.calls + 1;
    this.calls = this.calls + 1;
    return this.hasEngine;
  },
  canFly: null,
  getCanFly: function() { 
    vehicle.calls = vehicle.calls + 1;
    this.calls = this.calls + 1;
    return this.canFly; 
  }
}

let boat = Object.create(vehicle);
boat.canFly = false;

let sailboat = Object.create(boat);
sailboat.hasEngine = false;

let fishingBoat = Object.create(boat);
fishingBoat.hasEngine = true;

console.log(vehicle.calls);
// 0
console.log(boat.calls);
// 0
console.log(sailboat.calls);
// 0

sailboat.getHasEngine();

console.log(vehicle.calls);
// 1
console.log(boat.calls);
// 1
console.log(sailboat.calls);
// 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of this line in `getHasEngine`:

```
vehicle.calls = vehicle.calls + 1;
```

That's directly accessing the `vehicle` object. Since `boat` doesn't have its own `calls` property, it inherits it from `vehicle`, so `boat.calls` is 1.

> Also, why is `sailboat.calls` set to 2 after only calling `getHasEngine()` once?

Also because of that line: It sets `vehicle.calls` to `1`, and at that point, `sailboat` doesn't have its own `calls`, so it inherits the property. Then on the next line when you do:

```
this.calls = this.calls + 1;
```

that's *reading* `vehicle.calls` (1), adding 1 to it, and then assigning the result (2) to `sailboat.calls`.

Let's throw some ASCII-art at it. After creating your objects but before callling `getHasEngine`, you have this in memory (omitting details):

```
                                                          +−−−−−−−−−−+
vehicle−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>| (object) |
                                                      |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                      |   | calls: 0 |
                                                      |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | 
boat−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>|   (object)    |  | 
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | 
                               |   | [[Prototype]] |−−+ 
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     
                               |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
sailboat−−−>|   (object)    |  |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
            | [[Prototype]] |−−+
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note that neither `boat` nor `sailboat` has a `calls` property.

After `getHasEngine` is called once, you have this — note that `sailboat` now has a `calls` property (because it was created by `this.calls = this.calls + 1;`):

```
                                                          +−−−−−−−−−−+
vehicle−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>| (object) |
                                                      |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                      |   | calls: 1 |
                                                      |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | 
boat−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>|   (object)    |  | 
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | 
                               |   | [[Prototype]] |−−+ 
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     
                               |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
sailboat−−−>|   (object)    |  |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
            | [[Prototype]] |−−+
            | calls: 2      |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Here's a version with some logging to help show that a bit:

```js
let vehicle = {
  calls: 0,
  hasEngine: null,
  getHasEngine: function() {
    console.log("updating vehicle.calls");
    vehicle.calls = vehicle.calls + 1;
    console.log("vehicle.calls is now vehicle.calls");
    console.log("About to update this.calls, does this have calls?", this.hasOwnProperty("calls"));
    this.calls = this.calls + 1;
    console.log("Just updated this.calls, does this have calls?", this.hasOwnProperty("calls"));
    return this.hasEngine;
  },
  canFly: null,
  getCanFly: function() { 
    vehicle.calls = vehicle.calls + 1;
    this.calls = this.calls + 1;
    return this.canFly; 
  }
}

let boat = Object.create(vehicle);
boat.canFly = false;

let sailboat = Object.create(boat);
sailboat.hasEngine = false;

let fishingBoat = Object.create(boat);
fishingBoat.hasEngine = true;

console.log(vehicle.calls);  // 0
console.log(boat.calls);     // 0
console.log("boat has calls?", boat.hasOwnProperty("calls"));
console.log(sailboat.calls); // 0
console.log("sailboat has calls?", sailboat.hasOwnProperty("calls"));

sailboat.getHasEngine();

console.log(vehicle.calls);  // 1
console.log(boat.calls);     // 1
console.log("boat has calls?", boat.hasOwnProperty("calls"));
console.log(sailboat.calls); // 2
console.log("sailboat has calls?", sailboat.hasOwnProperty("calls"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you remove the `vehicle.calls =` line, you see it stop happening:

```js
let vehicle = {
  calls: 0,
  hasEngine: null,
  getHasEngine: function() {
    //vehicle.calls = vehicle.calls + 1;
    this.calls = this.calls + 1;
    return this.hasEngine;
  },
  canFly: null,
  getCanFly: function() { 
    //vehicle.calls = vehicle.calls + 1;
    this.calls = this.calls + 1;
    return this.canFly; 
  }
}

let boat = Object.create(vehicle);
boat.canFly = false;

let sailboat = Object.create(boat);
sailboat.hasEngine = false;

let fishingBoat = Object.create(boat);
fishingBoat.hasEngine = true;

console.log(vehicle.calls);  // 0
console.log(boat.calls);     // 0
console.log(sailboat.calls); // 0

sailboat.getHasEngine();

console.log(vehicle.calls);  // 0
console.log(boat.calls);     // 0
console.log(sailboat.calls); // 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much ... looks like I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how prototype inheritance worked in javascript! I see now, thanks for the excellent explanation!

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Thanks! I missed that `boat` was `sailboat`'s prototype. Fixed!